# fputcsv with custom headers

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

Trying to convert the following working code to PDO, the problem I am running into are the custom headings set in the `fputcsv($output,array)`. I really want to move away from all msql_ functions so I would greatly appreciate some help.

```
<?php
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=collections.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');


//MySQL Connect
removed

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Title','InclusiveDates','CollectionID','LocationID','Content','RangeValue','Section','Shelf','Extent','ExtentUnitID'));

// fetch the data

$rows = mysql_query('SELECT 
coll.title AS CollectionTitle, 
coll.inclusivedates AS InclusiveDates,
coll.ID AS CollectionID, 
collloc.LocationID,
collloc.Content,
collloc.RangeValue,
collloc.Section,
collloc.Shelf,
collloc.Extent,
collloc.ExtentUnitID
FROM tblCollections_Collections coll 
JOIN tblCollections_CollectionLocationIndex collloc 
ON collloc.CollectionID = coll.id 
ORDER BY coll.ID');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);

?>
```

I have gotten this far, without getting it to work. The problem here is that I am not able to set custom column names in the CSV file and it also does not export to a CSV.

```
<?php
$conn = removed


$query = "SELECT 
coll.title AS CollectionTitle, 
coll.inclusivedates AS InclusiveDates,
coll.ID AS CollectionID, 
collloc.LocationID,
collloc.Content,
collloc.RangeValue,
collloc.Section,
collloc.Shelf,
collloc.Extent,
collloc.ExtentUnitID
FROM tblCollections_Collections coll 
JOIN tblCollections_CollectionLocationIndex collloc 
ON collloc.CollectionID = coll.id 
ORDER BY coll.ID";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$data = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

$header = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if(empty($header)){ // do it only once!
  $header = array_keys($row); // get the columnnames
  fputcsv($data, $header); // put them in csv
}

echo "Success";
// Export every row to a file
fputcsv($data, $row);
}
?>
```

Comment: How is the problem related to PDO / mysql? You are doing fundamentally different things where the csv file is concerned in the two scripts.

Comment: No, I'm just not able to produce the same result with PDO instead of mysql_. :-(

Comment: How do you know? You have changed so much and are outputting to a different medium it's hard to tell where the problem is. You should start with *just* switching to PDO and change the other logic when you have that working.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you have to `fclose` the file?

Comment: The output from PDO is the same as that from mysql_, ie associative array. So it should be simple to change from one to another. PS as you are not using bound parameters you can use [**query()**](http://uk1.php.net/pdo.query) instead of `prepare()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, it appears to work just as the original one. If you have any concerns please let me know, it works as intended and I got rid of the mysql_ functions.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=collections.csv');

try {
$conn = removed
  }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT 
coll.title AS CollectionTitle, 
coll.inclusivedates AS InclusiveDates,
coll.ID AS CollectionID, 
collloc.LocationID,
collloc.Content,
collloc.RangeValue,
collloc.Section,
collloc.Shelf,
collloc.Extent,
collloc.ExtentUnitID
FROM tblCollections_Collections coll 
JOIN tblCollections_CollectionLocationIndex collloc 
ON collloc.CollectionID = coll.id 
ORDER BY coll.ID";

$results = $conn->query($sql);

// Pick a filename and destination directory for the file
// Remember that the folder where you want to write the file has to be writable
$filename = "collections.csv";

// Actually create the file
// The w+ parameter will wipe out and overwrite any existing file with the same name
$handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// Write the spreadsheet column titles / labels
fputcsv($handle,   array('Title','InclusiveDates','CollectionID','LocationID','Content','RangeValue','Section','Shelf','Extent','ExtentUnitID'));

// Write all the user records to the spreadsheet
foreach($results as $row)
{
fputcsv($handle, array($row['CollectionTitle'], $row['InclusiveDates'], $row['CollectionID'], $row['LocationID'], $row['Content'], $row['RangeValue'], $row['Section'], $row['Shelf'], $row['Extent'], $row['ExtentUnitID']));
}

// Finish writing the file
fclose($handle);

?>
```